# How to refer to the same parent/grandparent scope with nested loops?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have nested loops with Knockout. I would like to refer to something in a parent "scope". If you see below I always want to refer to the same parent/grandparent regardless how deep I nest the loops. I have seen the "with" binding, not sure it will help me. Is there any way I can create an alias to a particular scope, so further down in the nested loop I can refer to this alias and still be able to refer to the scope of the current loop also?

```
    <!-- Somewhere up there is the "scope" I want to capture -->
    <!-- ko foreach: getPages() -->
        <span data-bind="text: pageName" ></span>
        <button data-bind="click: $parents[1].myFunction()" >Press me</button>
        <!-- ko foreach: categories -->
             <span data-bind="text: categoryName" ></span>
             <button data-bind="click: $parents[2].myFunction()" >Press me</button>
            <!-- ko foreach: questions -->
                <span data-bind="text: questionText" ></span>
                <button data-bind="click: $parents[3].myFunction()" >Press me</button>
             <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`foreach` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) supports `as` aliases as does the [(custom) `withProperties` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html).

```
<!-- ko withProperties: { book: $root.getBook() } -->
  <!-- ko foreach: {data: book.pages, as: 'page'} -->
    <span data-bind="text: page.pageName" ></span>
    <button data-bind="click: book.bookClicked" >Press me</button>
    <!-- ko foreach: {data: page.categories, as: 'category'} -->
      <span data-bind="text: category.categoryName" ></span>
      <button data-bind="click: page.pageClicked" >Press me</button>
      <!-- etc -->
    <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

*None* of my declarative bindings directly use `$parent`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the [@user2864740 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20016185/3345644) is that **it doesn't work out of the box [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/ck0jqe0d/17/result/)**.

The first issue:

> The binding 'withProperties' cannot be used with virtual elements

To fix that simply add the following code:

```
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.withProperties = true;
```

After that, you'll get another exception:

> Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: 'book' is
>   undefined; Bindings value: foreach: {data: book.pages, as: 'page'}

Which indicates that the `withProperties` isn't working at all - it hasn't created the `book` property in the binding context for its child bindings as you might expect.

Below is the **fully working and reusable custom binding ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/ck0jqe0d/16/result/))**:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.withProperties = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Make a modified binding context, with a extra properties, and apply it to descendant elements
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            innerBindingContext = bindingContext.extend(value);

        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerBindingContext, element);

        // Also tell KO *not* to bind the descendants itself, otherwise they will be bound twice
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.withProperties = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you
[Calling a function in a parent's scope in nested view model](http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/browse_thread/thread/40e57536d1f71910/c186e29d5fb1ae96?lnk=gst&q=parent%5Bi%5D#c186e29d5fb1ae96)

and the jsfiddle demo
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joemcbride/5NLGA/)